# Problemas em salvar um item selecionado no Dropdownlistfor utilizando uma ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, dropdownlist

Estou tentando salvar uma alteração que tento fazer selecionando uma Categoria em um `Dropdownlistfor`.

**Tipo assim:**
[image: View de edição de uma SubCategoria]

Fico acompanhando o *Debug* e a *View* está enviando a Categoria selecionada, mas não estou conseguindo persistir essa alteração.

Minha Controller de SubCategoria está assim:

```
 // GET: SubCategorias/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        SubCategoriaViewModel subCategoriaViewModel =
            _subCategoriaAppService.ObterPorId(id.Value);

        subCategoriaViewModel.Categorias = _categoriaAppService.ObterTodas();

        if (subCategoriaViewModel == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return View(subCategoriaViewModel);
    }

    // POST: SubCategorias/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(SubCategoriaViewModel subCategoriaViewModel)
    {            
        _subCategoriaAppService.Atualizar(subCategoriaViewModel);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Meu método para atualizar está assim:

```
public SubCategoriaViewModel Atualizar(
        SubCategoriaViewModel subCategoriaViewModel)
    {
        //var categoriaSelecionada =
        //     _categoriaService.ObterPorId(subCategoriaViewModel.CategoriaId);
        subCategoriaViewModel.Categoria =
            _categoriaService.ObterPorId(subCategoriaViewModel.CategoriaId);

        var subCategoria =
            Mapper.Map<SubCategoriaViewModel,
            SubCategoria>(subCategoriaViewModel);

        //subCategoria.Categoria = categoriaSelecionada;
        _subCategoriaService.Atualizar(subCategoria);

        return subCategoriaViewModel;
    }
```

Na minha *View*:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categoria, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaId,
           new SelectList(Model.Categorias, "CategoriaId", "CategoriaNome"), new { @class = "form-control" })              
        </div>
    </div>
```

Minha *ViewModel*

```
public class SubCategoriaViewModel
{
    public SubCategoriaViewModel()
    {
        SubCategoriaId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid SubCategoriaId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Preencha o nome da SubCategoria."))]
    [MaxLength(60, ErrorMessage = ("Máximo {0} caracteres."))]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = ("Mínimo {0} caracteres."))]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    public string SubCategoriaNome { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CategoriaViewModel> Categorias = new List<CategoriaViewModel>();
    public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }

    //[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    //public DomainValidation.Validation.ValidationResult ValidationResult { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

}
```

O interessante é que se eu modificar o nome da SubCategoria ele persisti! Qualquer coisa, este o caminho de como estou tentando persistir isso https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohz5C.jpg

Comment: Como é a estrutura de subCategoriaViewModel ? Inclua na pergunta.

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Iago Frota, poste a solução do problema e depois marque a sua resposta como aceita(acredito que libera apenas dois dias depois). Para que futuros usuários que estão com um problema igual ou parecido saibam o que fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muita conversa com duas pessoas boas de coração (**Tiago Silva e LP. Gonçalves**), conseguimos entender o problema.

O problema estava em como eu estava tratando o Tipo de Associação para salvar e/ou alterar minhas entidades no banco de dados usando o *Entity Framework*.

Antes das solução, eu estava usando **Associação Independente** que foi uma das primeiras formas de associação entre entidades e que utilizava orientação a objetos para fazer essa associação. Como já devem saber, eu estava utilizando erradamente o recurso. Então na conversa com o **Tiago Silva** ele me explicou o erro e porque seria melhor utilizar **Associação por chave estrangeira (*Foreign Key*)**.

O que mudou foi minha classe de aplicação, que agora está assim:

```
public SubCategoriaViewModel Atualizar(
        SubCategoriaViewModel subCategoriaViewModel)
    {
        var categoriaSelecionada =
             _categoriaService.ObterPorId(subCategoriaViewModel.CategoriaId);

        var subCategoria =
            Mapper.Map<SubCategoriaViewModel,
            SubCategoria>(subCategoriaViewModel);

        subCategoria.Categoria = categoriaSelecionada;
        _subCategoriaService.Atualizar(subCategoria);

        return subCategoriaViewModel;
    }
```

E, houve a adição da propriedade `public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }` na classe de domínio SubCategoria, para servir como chave estrangeira na associação entre Categoria e SubCategoria (`1:N`). Segue o código:

```
public class SubCategoria
{
    public Guid SubCategoriaId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoriaNome { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

    public SubCategoria()
    {
        SubCategoriaId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Produtos = new List<Produto>();
    }        
}
```

Quem quiser dar uma olhada no material que eu li sobre o tema, segue os links

- [Chave estrangeira e Associação Independente no Entity Framework](http://www.tiselvagem.com.br/desenvolvimento/chave-estrangeira-e-associacao-independente-no-entity-framework/)
- [Foreign key e Independent Associations no Entity Framework (pt-BR)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9312.foreign-key-e-independent-associations-no-entity-framework-pt-br.aspx)
- [Chave estrangeira e Associação Independente no Entity Framework](https://efkey.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Agora que eu vi essa resposta rapaz! Esqueça os meus comentários anteriores!

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem seu problema, a solução é bem simples, basta apenas que você preencha a `CategoriaId` antes de chamar a view.

Pois, como você sabe, `CategoriaId` é responsável pelo valor do objeto selecionado no dropdown, se você não inicializar essa variável com o valor correto, o dropdown será exibido a opção `default` que no seu caso é o primeiro objeto da lista de `Categorias`.

**A solução do seu problema reside em:**

```
subCategoriaViewModel.CategoriaId = Id.value;
```

Não entendi bem sua estrutura, mas é o id da categoria que você salvou no bd.

Comment: Desde já agradeço sua atenção! Mas `CategoriaId` eu uso apenas pra facilitar para uso de persistência. Sua sugestão, `subCategoriaViewModel.CategoriaId = Id.value;` seria dentro do método do _Controller_?

Comment: Fiz um teste agora. Selecionei uma certa Categoria ([imagem](http://imgur.com/a/cNGMb)). Esse é o Id correto da Categoria que eu selecionei. Mas eu não sei pq, não está salvando essa alteração. Já um fiz teste para saber qual o estado do `EntityState` antes do `SaveChanges()` e o seu estado é `Modifield`.

Comment: Sobre a minha estrutura, estou utilizando conceitos de DDD

Comment: @IagoFrota sim, seria no controller mesmo, no get, antes de ir para a view. Mas sua estrutura do BD, como é o relacionamento das entidades ? Quando vc salva, você cria um objeto que se relaciona com categoria 1:1 ou 1:n, você não salva o Id desse objeto para referência ?

Comment: Meu relacionamento é 1:N. Utilizo associação independente no EF. Tipo, quando crio uma nova SubCategoria eu faço [assim](http://imgur.com/a/fxbga). Quando quero procurar algum registro, utilizo o método `ObterPorId(Guid Id)` que retorna um uma SubCategoria.

Comment: Como está o código do seu método       _subCategoriaService.Atualizar(subCategoria); ?

Comment: @GabrielSimas Ele seria um método genérico. Segue o [código](http://imgur.com/a/w1DVp). Eu tenho um _breakpoint_ em todas as linhas deste método. O `EntryState` é `modified`. Desde já, agradeço sua intenção de ajudar!

Comment: @IagoFrota, estou sempre à disposição para ajudar, não precisa agradecer. Também desenvolvo com os conceitos do DDD e não vi erro em sua arquitetura, porém, pelo trecho de código que você me mostrou, vc chamou a Entry de seu DbContext, utilizou attach e depois mudou o estado para Modified. Você só usa Attach quando está usando uma sessão fora da sessão atual e não é bem isso que parece ocorrer, já experimentou retirar o attach? Sempre que vc dá um commit, via SaveChanges, ele finaliza a sessão, logo vai dar sempre erro se vc quiser efetuar outra operação em seguida, te recomendo o Unit of Work

Comment: @IagoFrota Se o seu dbContext está usando a mesma conexão ou sessão, você não precisa usar attach pois aí existe quase uma sobreposição de threads e elas não são sincronizadas fazendo com que os seus objetos attachados fiquem fora da thread que gerencia a conexão atual com o BD e isso pode estar influenciando o seu trabalho. Se vc está utilizando o DDD creio que vc esteja injetando o DBContext na Infra e a utilizando nas camadas de negócio e aplicação, então não tem necessidade de criar um espaço paralelo ao que já está aberto, por isso falei o UoW onde vc dá um commit só no final da operação

Comment: @GabrielSimas Bem interessante seu comentário! Irei dar uma averiguada no código. Mesmo assim, obrigado!

Comment: @IagoFrota, dá uma olhada lá e diz pra gente o resultado, tá bom?